# Link to an open tab

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I want to create a link to an open tab on a different page.
Here's my html where the tab's are on:

```
// This are internal links
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab 4</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current"><p>some content</p></div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"><p>some content</p></div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"><p>some content</p></div>
<div id="tab-4" class="tab-content"><p>some content</p></div>
```

I use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  })
})
```

Now I have this link on an external page, I want to redirect to the page with the tabs and show the content of tab 2:

```
<a href="tabpage.html#tab-2>Some link</a>
```

This is not working, can anyone help me? Maybe with an onclick() in the a element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the hash in the url when page loads and trigger a click on corresponding `<li>`

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your existing tabs click listener
  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() { .... })
  // get hash from url
  var hash = location.hash;
  // check if tab matching hash exists
  if (hash && $(hash).length) {
    // now trigger click on appropriate tab
    $('.tab-link[data-tab="' + hash.slice(1) + '"]').click();        
  }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though.. Can you give a little more info on what I have to exactly do? I'm still learning :)

Comment: same as what is shown in answer. Just add my new code after yours